# Make element to get full page's width

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to make a front page which is divided into 2 section (1/2 page's width for a section), and whenever someone is hovering over a section it should take 2/3 of the page's width.
When a section gets clicked it should take the width of the whole page.

- HTML / CSS / JavaScript:

```js
    const leftPanel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel--left')[0];
    const rightPanel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel--right')[0];

    const mouseEnterHandler = e => {
        e.target === leftPanel ? leftPanel.style.flexGrow = '2' : rightPanel.style.flexGrow = '2';
    };

    const mouseLeaveHandler = e => {
        e.target === leftPanel ? leftPanel.style.flexGrow = '1' : rightPanel.style.flexGrow = '1';
    };

    const clickLeftPanelHandler = e => {
            leftPanel.style.flexGrow = '1';
            rightPanel.style.flexGrow = '0';
            e.stopPropagation();
    };

    const clickRightPanelHandler = e => {
        leftPanel.style.flexGrow = '0';
        rightPanel.style.flexGrow = '1';
        e.stopPropagation();
    };

    leftPanel.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnterHandler);
    rightPanel.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnterHandler);

    leftPanel.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler);
    rightPanel.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler);

    leftPanel.addEventListener('click', clickLeftPanelHandler);
    rightPanel.addEventListener('click', clickRightPanelHandler);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: inherit;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 25px;
    transition: flex-grow 0.75s ease;
}

.panel--left {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.panel--right {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.panel--left:hover,
.panel--right:hover {
    flex-grow: 2;
}

.panel--left:active,
.panel--right:active {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.panel__title {
    color: #3a424a;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 1em;
    margin: 0 0 45px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.panel__header {
    color: #3a424a;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto 55px;
    max-width: 525px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.panel__description {
    color: #6d7d8c;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto 50px;
    max-width: 625px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="panel panel--left">
            <div class="panel__text-content">
                <p class="panel__title">Sample text</p>
                <h1 class="panel__header">Sample text</h1>
                <p class="panel__description">Phasellus nec semper ex, ac mollis eros. Maecenas diam nunc, iaculis id est vel, laoreet pulvinar nisl. Aenean vestibulum auctor nulla, a vulputate nibh mollis nec. Sed odio arcu, laoreet nec nulla quis, ornare tincidunt urna. Phasellus pellentesque quam sit amet erat consectetur dapibus.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="panel panel--right">
            <div class="panel__text-content">
                <p class="panel__title">Sample text</p>
                <h1 class="panel__header">Sample text</h1>
                <p class="panel__description">Phasellus nec semper ex, ac mollis eros. Maecenas diam nunc, iaculis id est vel, laoreet pulvinar nisl. Aenean vestibulum auctor nulla, a vulputate nibh mollis nec. Sed odio arcu, laoreet nec nulla quis, ornare tincidunt urna. Phasellus pellentesque quam sit amet erat consectetur dapibus.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I can't get how I can make the second section to shrink to 0. I know how flex-grow works, but it's the closest look that I could get.

Hope I have expressed myself understandably.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `width: 0` and dont forget about `padding: 0` for the second section when clicking on it

Comment: I've tried but it looks 'choppy': [codepen](https://codepen.io/eugen97/pen/qoaJMY).

Answer (score 0):

i have edited my code, and if i am not wrong, you want " on mouse hover, section will have 2/3 size and on click, the section will be of full size (page size). "

Code to replace :-

```
const mouseEnterHandler = e => {
     e.target === leftPanel ? leftPanel.style.width = '0' : rightPanel.style.width = '0'; 
};

const mouseLeaveHandler = e => {
    e.target === leftPanel ? leftPanel.style.width = '0' : rightPanel.style.widht = '0';
};

const clickLeftPanelHandler = e => {
        leftPanel.style.width= '100%';
        rightPanel.style.display = 'none';
    };  

const clickRightPanelHandler = e => {  
       leftPanel.style.display = 'none';
       rightPanel.style.width = '100%';
     };
```

you just need to replace the part of javascript with my code and see if it is what you need. please give me feedback on my answer. if it helps or not. thanks...

Comment: Here is the code, but not what i really was looking for: [codepen](https://codepen.io/eugen97/pen/qoaJMY)

Comment: so you want, section gets 2/3 size on mouse hover and on click it gets of full size (page size) ?

Comment: yes, so the effect i get on 2/3 works for me, but I want more like overlapping effect when user clicks on one side ( so the text from the non-selected side wont change it's width but will stay at 1/3, while the 2/3 side overlaps it at gets 1/1 ).

Comment: have you tried my edited javascript code. in that u will have hover effect and onclick , clicked section will have full width. and i think its resloved your question right?

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes to styling to give both hover and clicked achieve 2/3 and 100% respectively (currently added for panel--left but you can copy same for right panel also.). 
You just need to do following:

1. Append class "clicked" on click of element.

Hope this helps.

PS: scrollbar which you see is because of header font-size. But I presume you will handle the font in smaller viewports.

cheers, 
Ashok

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


.panel {
     height: inherit;
    display: inherit;
    padding: 25px;
    width:50%;
}

.panel--left {
    background-color: #ffffff;
   
}

.panel--left:hover{
   flex: 0 0 66%;
}

.panel--left.clicked{
   flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.panel--left.clicked+.panel--right{
   display:none;
}



.panel--right {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    
}

.panel__title {
    color: #3a424a;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 1em;
    margin: 0 0 45px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.panel__header {
    color: #3a424a;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto 55px;
    max-width: 525px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.panel__description {
    color: #6d7d8c;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto 50px;
    max-width: 625px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="panel panel--left ">
            <div class="panel__text-content">
                <p class="panel__title">Sample text</p>
                <h1 class="panel__header">Sample text</h1>
                <p class="panel__description">Phasellus nec semper ex, ac mollis eros. Maecenas diam nunc, iaculis id est vel, laoreet pulvinar nisl. Aenean vestibulum auctor nulla, a vulputate nibh mollis nec. Sed odio arcu, laoreet nec nulla quis, ornare tincidunt urna. Phasellus pellentesque quam sit amet erat consectetur dapibus.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="panel panel--right">
            <div class="panel__text-content">
                <p class="panel__title">Sample text</p>
                <h1 class="panel__header">Sample text</h1>
                <p class="panel__description">Phasellus nec semper ex, ac mollis eros. Maecenas diam nunc, iaculis id est vel, laoreet pulvinar nisl. Aenean vestibulum auctor nulla, a vulputate nibh mollis nec. Sed odio arcu, laoreet nec nulla quis, ornare tincidunt urna. Phasellus pellentesque quam sit amet erat consectetur dapibus.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```